# JMeter Beanshell Integer Error

Tags: java, loops, integer, jmeter, beanshell

i have problem with Integer in JMeter Beanshell Sampler/Pre/Post processor. I have some array of values, and i want to use each value of this array to set JMeterProperty for next use.

GOAL> have some N rows from query. For Example UPSTREAM column has diff values and i need it save them for next use. Because i will use them for call CMD.exe as parameters by "OS Processes Sampler".

```
So, if UPSTREAM_1=XXX, UPSTREAM_2=AAA, 
CMD.EXE will looks like: CMD.EXE -upstream_1 -upstream_2, etc.
```

---

From SQL i got Array of values

```
COUNT=31
UPSTREAM_#=31
UPSTREAM_1=XXX
UPSTREAM_2=AAA
....
```

In PostProcessor i set:

```
${__setProperty(COUNT, ${COUNT_1})};
```

I am trying this scrpit:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*; 
import java.io.*;

int max = Integer.parseInt(vars.get(${COUNT_1})); //--COUNT=31, Integer doesnt work
int n = vars.get(${COUNT_1}); //--COUNT=31, this also doesnt work

for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
   ${__setProperty(UPSTREAM_i, ${UPSTREAM_i})};
}
```

But JMeter log say that it dont know the "INT"

```
2016/10/03 14:52:13 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `` import java.util.*; import java.text.*;  import java.io.*;  int max = Integer.p . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method get( int ) not found in class'org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables' 
2016/10/03 14:52:13 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `` import java.util.*; import java.text.*;  import java.io.*;  int max = Integer.p . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method get( int ) not found in class'org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables'
```

Can somebody help me? Maybe i miss some libs or something. JRE/JDK i have.

---

UPDATE_1

User Variables all:

```
COUNT   ${__property(COUNT)}    Count of Rows from SQL Query
```

Test_Plan:

[image]

PostProcessor Log:

```
SamplerProperties:
variableNames=DATE,DOWNSTREAM,UPSTREAM,COUNT,etc.

JMeterVariables:
COUNT=31
COUNT_#=31
COUNT_1=31
COUNT_2=31
.....
DATE_#=31
DATE_1=04.10.2016
DATE_2=04.10.2016
.....
DOWNSTREAM_#=31
DOWNSTREAM_1=DDD11
DOWNSTREAM_2=DDD11
.....
UPSTREAM_#=31
UPSTREAM_1=XXX
UPSTREAM_2=AAA
....
JMeterProperties:
COUNT= 31
DATE= 04.10.2016
DOWNSTREAM= DDD11
TEST= 1
```

Debug Loop log:

```
SamplerProperties:
BeanShellSampler.query=import java.util.*;
 import java.text.*; 
 import java.io.*;
 int n = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("COUNT")); 
 for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
      props.setProperty("UPSTREAM_"+i, vars.get("UPSTREAM_i"));
 }
    JMeterVariables:
    COUNT=31
    COUNT_#=31
    COUNT_1=31
    COUNT_2=31
    .....
    DATE_#=31
    DATE_1=04.10.2016
    DATE_2=04.10.2016
    .....
    DOWNSTREAM_#=31
    DOWNSTREAM_1=DDD11
    DOWNSTREAM_2=DDD11
    .....
    UPSTREAM_#=31
    UPSTREAM_1=XXX
    UPSTREAM_2=AAA
    ....
    JMeterProperties:
    COUNT= 31
    DATE= 04.10.2016
    DOWNSTREAM= DDD11
    TEST= 1
```

This is in Jmeter log now:

```
2016/10/03 17:12:24 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.*;  import java.text.*;   import java.io.*;  int n = Integer.pa . . . '' : Method Invocation props.setProperty 
2016/10/03 17:12:24 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.*;  import java.text.*;   import java.io.*;  int n = Integer.pa . . . '' : Method Invocation props.setProperty
```

---

UPDATE_2

**UBIK LOAD PACK's solution works :), GOAL updated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Beanshell script has many errors:

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.text.*; 
 import java.io.*;
 int n = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("COUNT")); 
 for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
      props.setProperty("UPSTREAM_"+i, vars.get("UPSTREAM_"+i));
 }
```

Note what you are doing is setting in props (global) what you get from vars (specific to each user) , so this may be wrong.

Read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions

Comment: Beanshell samples still have some problem ..

<code>
Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.*;  import java.text.*;   import java.io.*;  int n = Integer.pa . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Integer.parseInt </code>

Comment: are you sure COUNT is really defined as a variable ? Can you show your test plan ? Add a DebugPostProcessor before Beanshell PostProcessor and show output ?thx

Comment: no COUNT comes from SQL too. But When i set GLOBAL VAR in User Defined Variables `COUNT = ${__property(COUNT)}` it get back another Error `int n = Integer.pa . . . '' : Method Invocation props.setProperty `

Comment: I fixed a little typo in my script above. Can you retry to see if second issue is fixed. First one (missing COUNT) comes from unavailable var COUNT

Comment: I will try it .. and do some UPDATE to the original

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, there are multiple problems with your approach.

1. `${__setProperty(COUNT, ${COUNT_1})};`

   ```
                         ^ here you set an extra space before the value
   ```

   Also to be totally clear, `vars` and `props` are different beasts and they don't have anything in common. If you set a property via [__setProperty](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function, you won't be able to access it via `vars.get()`, you will have to use `props.get()` instead.
2. `vars.get(${COUNT_1})`  won't work, you should have to change it to one of the following:

   - `vars.get("COUNT_1");
   - `${COUNT_1}

   In general it is not recommended to inline JMeter Functions and Variables into Beanshell (and other) scripts as they may be interpreted differently depending on their value.
3. With regards to

   > Method get( int ) not found in class'org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables'

   I don't know how you managed to put an integer into JMeter Variables, but if you did, you should be accessing it via [vars.getObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject(java.lang.String)) function like

   ```
   int n = vars.getObject("COUNT");
   ```
4. Troubleshooting tip: surround your code with the [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html), you will be able to get a way more informative error messages in *jmeter.log* file like:

   ```
   try {
       //your code here
   }
   catch (Throwable ex) {
       log.error("something wrong", ex);
       throw ex;
   }
   ```

I would also recommend getting familiarized with [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) guide

Comment: Thx a lot too, i just updated the goal at the beginning of Question